# Splitting data to multiple identical databases

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have scenario where there are 5 identical databases running on the same server and there could be more with different names. 
One database is connected with our test system and is being populated with data.
Now I have to split that data over to different other identical databases based on some criteria.

Please let me know what is the most efficient solution for this. For example triggers or SQL Jobs or C# bases custom Application or any other thing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say "split" do you mean copy? Is one database the canonical source of information, or could they all receive updates independently?

Comment: One database is attached to the main application and it will be updated through application, other databases will receive updates from him.  I used the Microsoft Synchronization Framework 2.1 to Sync the data across all nodes. Microsoft Sync Framework is a comprehensive synchronization platform that enables collaboration and offline access for applications, services, and devices with support for any data type, any data store, any transfer protocol, and any network topology.